# add 0's before string until len of string SQL

Tags: sql, string, char

I have data in column like

```
 107155
 11316
 1235
 197852348
.
.
.
```

I need add 0's until length of 16. Example:

```
 0000000000107155
 0000000000011316
 0000000000001235
 0000000197852348
.
.
.
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

using lpad can get you what you want in oracle.

```
select lpad('107155',16,'0') 
  from dual
--0000000000107155
```